# Django - Error importing module context_processors

Tags: django

Newbie question for you.

I am trying to create my first custom context processor

my settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'mmaprophet.context_processors.seasons.active'

)
```

My project directory is called "mmaprophet", so I created a folder called "context_processors", and in it, I created a file called "seasons.py". That file contains the function active defined above.

my seasons.py

```
from seasons.models import Season


def active(request):
    '''
    A context processor to add the "active season" to the current Context
    '''

    active_season = Season.objects.get(active=True)

    return {'active_season': active_season}
```

But then I get this error:

```
    ImproperlyConfigured at /
Error importing module mmaprophet.context_processors.seasons: "No module named models"
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    
Error importing module mmaprophet.context_processors.seasons: "No module named models"
Exception Location: /home/ymorin007/workspace/sites/mmaprophet.com/src/mmaprophet/context_processors/seasons.py in <module>, line 2
Python Executable:  /home/ymorin007/.virtualenvs/mmaprophet/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/ymorin007/workspace/sites/mmaprophet.com/src',
 '/home/ymorin007/workspace/sites/mmaprophet.com/src',
 '/home/ymorin007/.virtualenvs/mmaprophet/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/ymorin007/.virtualenvs/mmaprophet/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/ymorin007/.virtualenvs/mmaprophet/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/ymorin007/.virtualenvs/mmaprophet/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/ymorin007/.virtualenvs/mmaprophet/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/ymorin007/.virtualenvs/mmaprophet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 22 May 2014 13:13:31 -0400
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue was because I used the same name as my app "seasons" as the file inside my context_processors folder "seasons.py"

Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an empty `__init__.py` file to declare the folder as a Python module. You can import from files which are in folder with `__init__.py` or from the current folder only.

You may know it, but as a reminder, [from the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path.

---

Your Python path does not include the root of your project also, you should add it to be able to import things from there.

Comment: Still the same error.  I've added the __init__.py to the context_processors.  I'm using PyCharm and I've created the context_processors folder by selecting New Python Package.

Comment: Can you try without the project name before? Just `context_processors.seasons.active`? Also keep in mind to add default elements of Django if you need them: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS

Comment: Ok it is not the same error now: Error importing module mmaprophet.context_processors.seasons: "No module named models"

Comment: Is there a `seasons` app? Can you import models otherwise else? Is there not any dependency-cycle?

Comment: Yes I have a seasons app. This is not the right way to import the model?

Comment: Yes, it is. I don't see the root of your project in your Python Path list, it explains surely why it don't find any packages from there :-) You should add it, or run the Django server from this folder (maybe you will have to play with PyCharm settings). The path should be `'/home/ymorin007/workspace/sites/mmaprophet.com/src/mmaprophet'`